# Possible non-freed memory in mongocxx driver

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

If I run my app with valgrind on Linux, I get similar stack traces, like this:

```
==20124== 524,288 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1,065 of 1,065
==20124==    at 0x4C33D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20124==    by 0x77C999: bson_realloc (bson-memory.c:154)
==20124==    by 0x77CA04: bson_realloc_ctx (bson-memory.c:194)
==20124==    by 0x75E162: _mongoc_buffer_fill (mongoc-buffer.c:254)
==20124==    by 0x73324D: mongoc_stream_buffered_readv (mongoc-stream-buffered.c:240)
==20124==    by 0x733D09: mongoc_stream_readv (mongoc-stream.c:237)
==20124==    by 0x733E45: mongoc_stream_read (mongoc-stream.c:281)
==20124==    by 0x75DF38: _mongoc_buffer_append_from_stream (mongoc-buffer.c:200)
==20124==    by 0x6FB71C: mongoc_cluster_run_opmsg (mongoc-cluster.c:3468)
==20124==    by 0x6F5A7B: mongoc_cluster_run_command_monitored (mongoc-cluster.c:544)
==20124==    by 0x70A27A: _mongoc_cursor_run_command (mongoc-cursor.c:1052)
==20124==    by 0x70BAA1: _mongoc_cursor_response_refresh (mongoc-cursor.c:1673)
==20124==    by 0x70D09C: _prime (mongoc-cursor-find-cmd.c:36)
==20124==    by 0x70CEA4: _prime (mongoc-cursor-find.c:61)
==20124==    by 0x70A73E: _call_transition (mongoc-cursor.c:1204)
==20124==    by 0x70A962: mongoc_cursor_next (mongoc-cursor.c:1280)
==20124==    by 0x6528F0: mongocxx::v_noabi::cursor::iterator::operator++() (cursor.cpp:45)
==20124==    by 0x652C02: mongocxx::v_noabi::cursor::iterator::iterator(mongocxx::v_noabi::cursor*) (cursor.cpp:80)
==20124==    by 0x652B2D: mongocxx::v_noabi::cursor::begin() (cursor.cpp:67)
==20124==    ...
```

Valgrind command:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --num-callers=200 ./
```

The problem is that it is here after request is served out and according to it, the memory consumption won't decrease to the initial state.
The piece of code where it is come from:

```
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(document{} << "m" << matrixId << finalize);
    for(auto&& m : cursor) {
```

Some additional info:

- I use connection pooling and the acquire() method is used to get a client entry
- The initial implementation served every request on new thread, so thread create - exit guards the request execution. The issue raised when fixed number of thread pool is deployed and requests are served by these threads, so when thread exit after serving out the request, the issue gone away.

Can anybody help me, what is going wrong?

Comment: What is going wrong is a library that allocates a buffer and doesn't free it before terminating. Unless you are willing to dive into this library's sources, and figure out how to appropriately clean up memory when the library gets unloaded, there's nothing else to do. Except, perhaps, check the library's documentation to see if there's an explicit cleanup function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, yes, it seems like an issue in the MongoCxx driver, however I couldn't deal that is it a bug or a configuration setting.

Comment: As I mentioned, if every request spawn a new thread and destroy it when request is served, the issue gone away.
On the other hand, if the requests are served by long living threads, the driver won't clean up memory allocated by cursor.